# Cassandra DB Query for System Date

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have one table `customer_info` in a Cassandra DB & it contains one column as `billing_due_date`, which is date field (`dd-MMM-yy` ex. 17-AUG-21).  I need to fetch the certain fields from `customer_info` table based on `billing_due_date` where `billing_due_date` should be equal to system date +1.

Can anyone suggest a Cassandra DB query for this?

Comment: Can you post your table's primary key definition?  That's going to be an important consideration for any query.

Comment: transaction_id is primarykey , It is just generated through uuid().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fetch the certain fields from `customer_info` table based on `billing_due_date`
>
> `transaction_id` is primarykey , It is just generated through uuid()

Unfortunately, there really isn't going to be a good way to do this.  Right now, the data in the `customer_info` table is distributed across all nodes in the cluster based on a hash of the `transaction_id`.  Essentially, any query based on something other than `transaction_id` is going to read from multiple nodes, which is a query anti-pattern in Cassandra.

In Cassandra, you need to design your tables based on the queries that they need to support.  For example, choosing `transaction_id` as the sole primary key may distribute well, but it doesn't offer much in the way of query flexibility.

Therefore, the best way to solve for this query, is to create a query table containing the data from `customer_info` with a key definition of `PRIMARY KEY (billing_date,transaction_id)`.  Then, a query like this should work:

```
> SELECT * FROM customer_info_by_date
  WHERE billing_due_date = toDate(now()) + 2d;

 billing_due_date | transaction_id                       | name
------------------+--------------------------------------+---------
       2021-08-20 | 2fe82360-e314-4d5b-aa33-5deee9f03811 | Rinzler
       2021-08-20 | 92cb9ee5-dee6-47fe-b372-0829f2e384cd |     Clu

(2 rows)
```

Note that for this example, I am using the system date plus 2 days out. So in your case, you'll want to adjust the "duration" aspect from `2d` down to `1d`. Cassandra 4.0 allows date arithmetic, so this should work just fine if you are on that version.  If you are not, you'll have to do the "system date plus one" calculation on the app side.

Another way to go about this, would be to create a secondary index on `billing_due_date`, but I don't recommend that path as it will query multiple nodes to build the result set.

Comment: Thanks much , This helped.